# How would I use a SQL query for the following result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with the following entities:
[image: Survey Model]

[image: Question Model]

[image: Survey Question]

I also have an employee entity not shown here that has an id and name field that I would like to include in my query.

I need to create a query that if given a survey ID would return a list of results that look like this:

```
Survey.name  |  Survey.submitter_id  |  Survey.subject_id | question.text | survey_questions.answer_value |survey_questions.anonymous
```

Comment: please the query you tried so far

Comment: I think the required query would start with `SELECT` and include `FROM`. Do you have a query written for just one of the tables? That would be starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test the query but i think you will get the idea:

`SELECT s.name, sq.submitter_id, s.subject_id, q.text, sq.answer_value, sq.anonymous FROM surveys AS s 
JOIN survey_questions AS sq ON sq.survey_id = s.id
JOIN questions AS q ON sq.question_id = q.id
WHERE s.id = <your_value>`